# 'module' object has no attribute error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to django. I'm trying to build an app. But the problem is that there is function defined in views.py still when i try to start server it says 'module' object has no attribute.

stock/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from stock import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^stocks/$', views.stock_list),
    url(r'^stocks/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.stock_detail),
]
```

stock/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from stock.models import Stock
from stock.serializers import StockSerializer

class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    # An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON.

    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)

    @csrf_exempt
    def stock_list(request):
        # List all code snippets, or create a new snippet.
        if request.method == 'GET':
            stocks = Stock.objects.all()
            serializer = StockSerializer(stock, many=True)
            return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            data = JSONParser().parse(request)
            serializer = StockSerializer(data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return JSONResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
            return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)

    @csrf_exempt
    def stock_detail(request, pk):
        # Retrieve, update or delete a code snippet.
        try:
            stock = Stock.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Stock.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse(status=404)

        if request.method == 'GET':
            serializer = StockSerializer(stock)
            return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
        elif request.method == 'PUT':
            data = JSONParser().parse(request)
            serializer = StockSerializer(stock, data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
            return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
        elif request.method == 'DELETE':
            Stock.delete()
            return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

I'm getting following error

```
File "/users /ha/code/RiskAdvisor/riskadvisor/stock/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    url(r'^stocks/$', views.stock_list),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'stock_list'
```

Comment: Yes, because it doesn't. Double-check your indentation...

Comment: indentation but where indentation is wrong @jonrsharpe

Comment: Funnily enough, it's wrong where you define the functions that the error message is telling you aren't defined where you thought they were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, `stock_list` is a method inside the `JSONResponse` class (and `request` is expected to be of type `JSONResponse`, conventionally called `self`). Obviously it's not what you meant. It should be a simple module-level function. Simply dedent once.

```
class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    # An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON.

    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        ...

@csrf_exempt
def stock_list(request):
    ...
```

The IDE I use, [PyDev](http://www.pydev.org/), signals an error on your code:

> method stock_list should have self as first parameter

It also tells me that `serializer = StockSerializer(stock, many=True)` contains a typo - there's no `stock` variable. You probably meant `stocks`?

Use a good IDE.

Comment: problem you mentioned are there in code great IDE PyDev+Eclipse